# Почему сессия не закрывается, а продолжает работать после вывода результирующего набора данных?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, dba

Есть большая таблица.
После каждого запроса на эту таблицу, быстро показывается результирующий набор из 50 строк, но сессия продолжает работать. Если запустить аналогичный запрос, то появляется новый SID, и у всех в EVENT 'send bkld'.

Как вызывать `SELECT` больших таблиц, чтобы после показа N строк результирующего набора, сессия закрывалась, то есть не продолжалась загрузка таблицы в 'bkld'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем структура работы с данными в БД следующая:

- одно соединение (*connect*) может иметь от 0 до N сессий (*session*) БД
- одна сессия БД может открывать и закрывать один или более курсоров

Сессия и курсоры *должны быть закрыты явно*. Исключение: приложение или инструмент могут выполнять закрытие/разединение неявно.

Подробнее следует ознакомится с [концепциями БД в оф.документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/index.html).

На простом примере с SQL*Plus (см. комментарии):

```
$ sqlplus /nolog
-- пока нет соединения
SQL> connect user/pass@localhost/pdb1
Connected.
-- установленно соединение и открыта сессия БД
SQL> create table bigtab (id) as
  2  select rownum from xmlTable ('1 to 100000');

Table created.
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> exec open :rc for select * from bigtab;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
--обьявлен и открыт один курсор

SQL> declare ids sys.odciNumberList;
  2  begin  fetch :rc bulk collect into ids limit 50; end;
  3  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
-- считано 50 записей из открытого курсора
 
SQL> exec close :rc

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
-- курсор закрыт

SQL> disconnect
Disconnected from Oracle Database [...]
-- сессия БД закрыта, но соединение ещё осталось

SQL> exit
-- приложение закрыто, соединение разорванно
```